# How can i get exactly same result (result of image) with css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: responsive]

How can i get exactly same result (result of image) with css?
i am using bootstrap col-md-4 !

Comment: Its hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can achieve the result using "Media Objects" in Bootstrap. You
>   dont have to write explicit css code for the same. just go through the
>   link below:

**http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media**

> You have to just put HTML markup there!
>
> Your final code will look similar to this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="path for mobile img here" alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    description content here....!
  </div>
</div>
```